# Is it better to use drivers from a laptop or component vendor or Microsoft?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers

I have a Lenovo laptop (running Windows 10) and I have the choice of updating the drivers either via

- Microsoft Update
- or through [ThinkVantage System Update](https://support.lenovo.com/fr/en/documents/ht003029), the Lenovo updater
- or directly from the component vendor site (Nvidia for instance).

**Which one should I use to have an optimum between stability and drivers up-to-dateness?**

Answer (score 0):

If your laptop came with Windows 10, then I suppose Microsoft Update should be the best option in terms of stability, and a fairly good option for "up-to-dateness".

Downloading drivers from OEM websites like Lenovo's would not be as good in terms of "up-to-dateness" but if your OEM is officially supporting Windows 10 (as the default operating system), then stability would be guaranteed. If you upgraded to Windows 10, then even stability might not be that good.

In my case, I am using an HP Pavilion which came with Windows 8.1. I upgraded it to Windows 10 and even though HP added a Windows 10 tab on their drivers website for my device, HP did not provide the Intel Management Engine Interface driver which I needed to fetch manually from the Intel website to solve the shutdown problem (system would not shut down unless I downgraded my driver manually from v11.x to v9.x).

Downloading drivers directly from the component (ODM) websites would be perfect, as long as you have the time to set up each of them.

I recommend you stay with Microsoft Update, and manually install the drivers for Nvidia/Radeon cards (if you have any) since they roll out updates on fairly frequent basis, and for any device that causes problems (like IMEI in my case).